# link a library without lib as prefix in linux using MPC

Tags: linux, g++, mpc

i have to link a static library which doesn't have `lib` as a prefix in it's name. i know how to link with simple `g++` i.e as following

`g++ -l:"mylib.a" a.cpp`

i want to do the same using MPC. i tried following in MPC file. those are not working.

`lit_libs += $(LIB_NAME)` generates `g++ -l"mylib" a.cpp` which needs `lib` as prefix.

`pure_libs += $(LIB_NAME)` generates `g++ "mylib" a.cpp` which cannot find the library.

please give me option of `MPC` to link libraries which doesn't have `lib` has prefix in it.

Answer (score 0):

`pure_libs += -l:$(LIB_NAME).a`

this resolved my problem.